# Color the space under the ploted line in a pgfplot

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I have plotted some values on a pgfplot and I wish to color in red the part under the line. Some suggestion about a package or what I need to look into would be great. In this case googling it did not help me too much

My graph:
[image]

my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\datavisualization [school book axes, visualize as smooth line]
    data {
       x, y
    -1.9,0.001
-1.8,0.001
-1.7,0.002
-1.6,0.001
-1.5,0.01
-1.4,0.004
-1.3,0.005
-1.2,0.008
-1.1,0.01
-1,0.014
-0.9,0.029
-0.8,0.037
-0.7,0.056
-0.6,0.119
-0.5,0.187
-0.4,0.391
-0.3,0.667
-0.2,1.062
-0.1,1.648
0,2.418
0.1,2.454
0.2,1.829
0.3,1.243
0.4,0.809
0.5,0.537
0.6,0.319
0.7,0.178
0.8,0.101
0.9,0.06
1,0.035
1.1,0.019
1.2,0.018
1.3,0.014
1.4,0.019
1.5,0.004
1.6,0.004
1.7,0.002
1.8,0.003
1.9,0.001
2,0.003
2.1,0.001
2.2,0.002
2.3,0.001
2.4,0.001
};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I want it to look something like this:

[image]

Comment: @StefanPinnow, I don't understand how to use the fillbetween from the other question which you referenced. I don't have 2 plots. I have one line..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using e.g. PGFPlots `fillbetween` library. Please also have a look at the corresponding section in the PGFPlots manual or at other questions here on TeX.SX with the tag [fillbetween](/questions/tagged/fillbetween).

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /pgf/declare function={
            % normal distribution where \mean = mean and \stddev = sd}
            gauss(\mean,\stddev) = 1/sqrt(2*pi*\stddev^2) * exp(-((\x-\mean)^2)/(2*\stddev^2));
            % define xmin and xmax only once here and reuse them later
            xmin=-2;
            xmax=2;
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis on top,
        xmin=xmin,
        xmax=xmax,
        domain=xmin:xmax,
        samples=100,
    ]
        \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:xmin,0) -- (axis cs:xmax,0);

        \addplot [
            thick,
            name path=gauss,
        ] {gauss(0.1, 0.25)};
        % instead of using a function here you could also give table values or read a (table) file
       % \addplot table {<table> or <file name>};

        \addplot [
            fill=black!10,
        ] fill between [
            of=axis and gauss,
        ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Oh wow, I did not expect such a detailed answer. Thank you so much for your help and patience!