# Plot graph for cut-off

Tags: pgfplots

How can I plot a function like this with LaTeX?

[image]

But without being pointy (i.e. a smooth transition) and the function never reaching zero?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]

\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=1,
      xtick=\empty, % remove all ticks from x-axis
      ytick={0,1}, % remove all ticks from y-axis
      xlabel=$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  t_{mix}(\varepsilon)  \ \   \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ t$, 
      ylabel=\empty,
      axis lines=left, % default is to make a box around the axis
      samples = 100,
      domain=0:5,
      restrict y to domain=-0:1,
      legend pos=north east
      ]
    \addplot [black, samples = 100] {(x<0.638585)*(1 - exp(7*x)/100) + (!(x<0.638585))*(exp(-7* (x - 0.5))/3)};
    \addlegendentry{$d(t)$}
    \addplot [green, samples = 100] {(4)^(-1)};
    \addlegendentry{$\varepsilon$}
    \draw [dashed] (0.61678,-1) -- (0.61678,1);
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=1,
      ymin=0, ymax=1.05,
      xtick={ln(75)/7},
      xticklabels={$t_{mix}(\varepsilon)$},
      ytick=\empty,
      xlabel={$t$},
      x label style={at={(axis description cs:1,0)}},      
      axis lines=left,
]
\addplot[samples = 500, smooth] {x<0.63?(1-exp(7*x)/100):(exp(-20*(x-0.545)))};
\addlegendentry{$d(t)$}
\addplot[green, samples=2] {1/4};
\addlegendentry{$\varepsilon$}
\draw[dashed] ({ln(75)/7},0) -- (({ln(75)/7},1);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Thank you for the solution (and for improving some things in my previous one, I don't really know that well how to handle with plots on overleaf)

Comment: This is a graph made with PGFPlots in LaTeX. https://www.overleaf.com is just a website where you can write and compile LaTeX online.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, in case you are interested: Have a look at [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623650/95441) for an improved version of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an improved version of [hpekristiansen's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623587/95441) which is too long for a comment.

The main "issue" with the answer is, that way too many points are calculated. As you can see one can get the same result with only 25 points (instead of 500). For more details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=1,
        ymin=0, ymax=1.05,
        xtick={ln(75)/7},
        % ("mix" should be upright)
        xticklabels={$t_{\mathrm{mix}}(\varepsilon)$},
        ytick=\empty,
        xlabel={$t$},
        % (even better coordinate system to choose to place the `xlabel`)
        x label style={at={(xticklabel* cs:1)}},
        axis lines=left,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        % moved common stuff here
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        smooth,
        % only this `domain` is shown, so no need to calculate the default
        % `domain` which is from -5 to +5 ...
        domain=0:1,
        % ... with that the default number of `samples` (25) is enough
        % to have a `smooth` plot (when `smooth` is used as well)
%        samples=25,
        % don't show any markers
        no markers,
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]
        \addplot {x<0.63 ? 1-exp(7*x)/100 : exp(-20*(x-0.545))};
            \addlegendentry{$d(t)$}
        \addplot [green, samples=2] {1/4};
            \addlegendentry{$\varepsilon$}
        \draw[dashed] ({ln(75)/7},0) -- ({ln(75)/7},1);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think sometimes overleaf takes a lot to compile the code because of the high number of points I use for plots

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Great improvements. I especially learned to always give a domain - there is no such thing as adopting `xmin` and `xmax` when domain is missing. Personally, I would not move "common stuff" to `axis` from a few plots.

Comment: @hpekristiansen, thanks for the credit. As always everything has pros and cons. But most often I would say it would be benefitial to place at least `domain` in the `axis` options to avoid repetition. Here a link to a random answer I gave here on TeX.SX on how _I_ usually deal with stating `xmin` and `xmax` values without repeating myself. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/490635/95441